# variable inside watch not reactive vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am watching an array and if some conditions met I want to disable / modify other elements but no luck so far, as the variable already_answered is not reactive.

```
<input :disabled="already_answered" type="text" />

data: function() {
  return {
    already_answered: false,
    somearr: [],
  };
},

   watch: {
      somearr() {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.somearr.length; i++) {
          if (this.somearr[i]["id"] == 5) {
            this.already_answered = true
            break;
          }

        }

      },
    },
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ? And if you try to do something like `alert('foo')` just in the beggin of the watch of `somearr()` does something happend ?

Comment: I think I should apologize here, yes, I was terribly wrong, the code was working perfectly, just the somearr contents were not matched. Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to use watch(x) with computed(x), that solve that problem, because other methods doesn´t affects the direct array, so yo have to use a computed array to watch that changes